# How to fetch a record from db asynchronously while unit testing?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

In this unit test I would like to check if the device has been created and that the expiry date is 7 days in future.

```
database.py

import databases
database = databases.Database(settings.sqlalchemy_database_uri)
```

Unit Test:

```
from database.database import database

def test_successful_register_expiry_set_to_seven_days():
    response = client.post(
        "/register/",
        headers={},
        json={"device_id": "u1"},
    )
    assert response.status_code == 201
    query = device.select(whereclause=device.c.id == "u1")
    d = database.fetch_one(query)
    assert d.expires_at == datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0) + timedelta(days=7)
```

Because `d` is a coroutine object it fails with the message:

```
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'expires_at'
```

And I can't use `await` inside a unit test.

```
d = await database.fetch_one(query)
```

What am I missing, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is never awaited, your code returns the coroutine before that semaphore going in to the scheduler.

If you are using an asynchronous driver, you need to await it. Are there any workarounds for this? Yes.

You can use `asyncio.run(awaitable)` to run the coroutine inside an event loop.

```py
import asyncio

d = asyncio.run(database.fetch_one(query))
```

If you have an currently running event loop you may want to use that event loop instead. You can achieve that by `asyncio.get_event_loop()`, which will run the function inside the running loop.

```py
import asyncio

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(database.fetch_one(query))
```

You can also use `@pytest.mark.asyncio` decorator (see [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/async-tests/#example)).

```py
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def dummy():
    await some_awaitable()
```

Comment: Sadly I get this error: `RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-4' coro=<Database.fetch_one() running at /Users/houmie/.pyenv/versions/v391/lib/python3.9/site-packages/databases/core.py:146> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /Users/houmie/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py:184]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop`

Comment: Hmm, i suppose databases creates the event loop and tries to execute inside it. Can you try getting the runinng loop and using it instead with; `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(database.fetch_one(query))`. If it does not works, you can also try `pytest.mark_asyncio`.

Comment: `@pytest.mark.asyncio` still throws `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`.  But the other solution worked. You may want to update your answer. Thank you (If you have an idea how to further simplify it with `@pytest.mark.asyncio` I would like to know. :)

Comment: I found it in the documentation. And yes it works! https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/async-tests/#example

Comment: Great! I am glad both worked. I will update the answer with alternative solutions.